# Running mpirun job in a bash script

Tags: bash, mpi

I am having issue running an mpirun job one after the other in a bash script. Below is a sample bash script I used. Let's call it `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

mpirun --map-by hwthread --use-hwthread-cpus ./myprogram.x myfile1.ini &> out1.txt;

mpirun --map-by hwthread --use-hwthread-cpus ./myprogram.x myfile2.ini &> out2.txt;
```

When I run this, both instances of `myprogram.x`, each with different configuration .ini file will run together, which is not how I intend it to be. I want the first `mpirun` job to be completed first before the second one will start. It feels like there's an obvious solution somewhere but I have tried searching in StackOverflow and couldn't find any relevant solution.

Any help?

Comment: Why don't you use a lock file and restrict `myprogram.x`  to run only one instance at a time? Isn't it possible?

Comment: `mpirun ... 2>&1 > out.txt`

Answer (score 0):

`"&>"` is not recognized by /bin/sh. You should write on the top of your script to make it run as you intend:

```
!/bin/bash
```

In this way you are running both commands in background, that's why they are running simultaneously.